# Existing Apache .htaccess to Nginx Config

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I think ive got lost a little bit.

I tried a few solutions, but i dont get one part. Everything has to be handled by index.php and i can not get it work in nginx. I keep learning Nginx as its awesome but would really appreciate some quick help from somebody.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And my Nginx config is :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /folder;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name hostname.com;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files = $uri @missing;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
        location @missing {
           rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/index.php permanent;
}
}
```

Can somebody point me to the right direction? Thanks

Comment: And what exactly is your question? What does "not get it to work" mean? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hey Maciej,
my bad. I have an old cms which my client want to have on their new nginx server. The problem is the application use to work so it took whatever.php "whatever" and used it as dynamic headings. So the php application reads index.php as the homepage. Anything else is goes as a heading and there is a mysql lookup for the specific page content.

Comment: Please edit your original question with all these details. Make sure you clearly state the question and present the undesired and desired effects.

Answer (score 0):

Any URI which does not end with `.php` is processed by the `location /` block. If you want to implement your Apache `.htaccess` rules, that is where it should be done. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_route_=$uri;
}
```

In the `location ~ \.php$` block, you should guard against [passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php), for example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard,
Thanks for the response. I have tried the aboe solutions before i came to stackoverflow.com. Still it does not work. This is an old site, but the PHP function is really oldschool however the desing is fix and the cliens want to keep everything. But it was on apache. I tested it works on apacehe, whatever-its-here.php is going to be the title of the page its like ond school dynamic titles. At the moment this is what i get still, hostname.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500